# <ul> li float dont fill the block

Tags: css, html-lists

Each time i get this problem.. but the old fix doesn't work this time...

I have a `<ul>` full of `<li>` that are floated left

those are perfect.... but i like to have a nice box around... and i style the `<ul>`

but the `<ul>` is "sort of empty" because the insides are floated...

the trick with the `<div style="clear:both">` dont work...
but event if it work.. it's ugly..

what is the "right" method to get the `<ul>` a size.. without hardcoding the width and height ?

---

as both point out... the solution was : OVERFLOW

here is the explaination (for future ference) : 
The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.
The new solution

It was Alex Walker who first posted a new, simpler solution, though he gives the credits for actually inventing it to Paul O'Brien. In any case, the solution seems to be:

div.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: at the end.. i used : hidden.... to not have any scrollbar !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set overflow to auto for the `ul` elements..

```
ul{overflow:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution:

Set ul properties:

```
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: 1px solid #000;
```

Set its li properties:

```
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
```

This worked for me. The ul is now wrapped around the li.

Note: However the space between two li can't be cleared in this sense.